# Indexed column throws threshold error while filtering based on range

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, sharepoint-rest-api, list-view-threshold

We have a list with over 1M items. The end goal is to filter the column InvDate based on date range.

The InvDate is an indexed single line of text column , However it throws the List View Threshold error while getting the item using RestAPI

**Code**

```
function FilterDate()
{
  //var initialUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('ClaimListNew')/Items?$select=ID,*";
  
var sdate = $('#sdate').val();
var edate = $('#edate').val();


var myQuery= _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl +"/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('MyList')/items?$select=ID*";
myQuery+="&$filter=InvDate ge '" +sdate+ "' and InvDate le '" +edate+ "'";
myQuery+="&$top=4999";
myQuery+="&$orderby=ID desc";


// start the process
var getAllItemsRequest = GetAllItems(myQuery);

// wait for it all to complete
getAllItemsRequest.done(function (allItems) {

console.log(allItems);
   
  
    
}).fail(function (error) {
    console.warn("Error getting all items");
    console.warn(JSON.stringify(error));
});
}
```

**Function to get all the list items**

```
function GetAllItems(requestUrl) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    $.ajax({
        url: requestUrl,
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        }
    }).done(function (thisResult) {
        if (thisResult.d.__next) {
            // if the __next property is present,
            // that measn that there's more to get,
            // so don't start resolving things yet,
            // just make the next request
            var nextRequest = GetAllItems(thisResult.d.__next);
            
            // since GetAllItems returns a promise,
            // we have to wait for that promise to resolve
            // before resolving the promise we made 
            // at the beginning of this function
            nextRequest.done(function(nextResult) {
                // nextResult should be a plain array of items,
                // so we need to combine that with the array
                // of items we got in this call in thisResult.d.results
                var combinedResults = thisResult.d.results.concat(nextResult);
                
                // then resolve the combined results back up to the next level
                deferred.resolve(combinedResults);

            }).fail(function(error) {
                deferred.reject(error);
            });
        } else {
            // __next doesn't exist, so
            // there's nothing more to get, so
            // start resolving the nested promises
            deferred.resolve(thisResult.d.results);
        }
    }).fail(function (result) {
        deferred.reject(result);
    });
    return deferred.promise();
};
```

The above function has retrieved all 1 Million items without any filters as below

`var myQuery= _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl +"/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ClaimlistNew')/items?$select=ID,*";` 
[image]

When we use query with the below filter , we get the threshold error

`var myQuery= _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl +"/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('MyList')/items?$select=ID*"; myQuery+="&$filter=InvDate ge '" +sdate+ "' and InvDate le '" +edate+ "'"; myQuery+="&$top=4999"; myQuery+="&$orderby=ID desc";`

The end goal is to filter the InvDate column with the date range.

Would be grateful if anyone could let me know how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 1):

As the column type is text so Greater than and Less than condition will not work so you should first convert the column type to Date or DateTime.

Then you need to check below.

1. The date should be in proper format. you can pass ISOString format date
2. `&` should be used as `&amp;`

so the FilterDate function should look like below

```
function FilterDate()
{
  //var initialUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('ClaimListNew')/Items?$select=ID,*";
  
var sdate = new Date($('#sdate').val()).toISOString();
var edate = new Date($('#edate').val()).toISOString();


var myQuery= _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl +"/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('MyList')/items?$select=ID*";
myQuery+="&amp;$filter=(InvDate ge DateTime'"+sdate+"') and (InvDate le DateTime'"+edate+"'");
myQuery+="&amp;$top=4999";
myQuery+="&amp;$orderby=ID desc";


// start the process
var getAllItemsRequest = GetAllItems(myQuery);

// wait for it all to complete
getAllItemsRequest.done(function (allItems) {

console.log(allItems);
   
  
    
}).fail(function (error) {
    console.warn("Error getting all items");
    console.warn(JSON.stringify(error));
});
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying Harminder. The date is in correct format. As suggested by you , would use &amp and check the behavior

Comment: Harminder , this seems to work , However it is getting all the entries from the list and not filtering it based on date range. The InvDate field is an indexed single line of text.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @Vivek can you try the filter like (InvDate ge DateTime'sDate') and(InvDate le DateTime'edate')and top as last parameter. I have tried the same and getting correct results

Comment: Harminder would you mind editing your answer and elaborating it? I am getting the dates from jquery datepicker and passing it to query dynamically. Do you mean I need to parse the value received from jquery datepicker to DateTime's Date?

Comment: @Vivek updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help , I have an issue converting the 2nd datepicker to IOString and it gives me invalid time error. Are of aware of this. I also used moment.js , However .toISOString is returning April in place of May. Any idea?

Comment: Harminder your solution would only work if the column is of type datetime. In my scenario my column is single line of text. Please check this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36897613/rest-date-range-filter-on-a-singleline-text-column

Comment: @Vivek as the column type is single line of text so Greater than and Less than will not work. so better you convert the columns in the Date/Date  time type

Comment: Unfortunately we have 2 million records... Will look for a workaround or convert it

Comment: Harminder I tried your suggestion and used the Date Column and its giving me the exact same behavior , Not sure how is this working for you

Comment: @Vivek can you please share the update code or does it look same like the solution given above?

Comment: Its the exact same code , the only difference is I am using Modified in place of InvDate

Comment: @Vivek have you added Modified in the index columns?

Comment: Yes It was indexed

Comment: @Vivek I am using this query on my list having 50k items and it is running fine. requeste created is date field and it is indexed. the date value provided in filter condition is ISODateTime. _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Requests')/items?$select=requestcreated,ID,Title&amp;$filter=(requestcreated%20gt%20DateTime%272021-07-01T00:00:00Z%27)&amp;$top=500&amp;$orderby=ID%20desc

Comment: I'm using the exact same query , not sure why it's not working for me. The difference is I have 2M items in the list. Also multiple filter conditions are being used along with ge and le. Can you please check if the desired results are returned when you modify your query and use le and ge?